# Redshift DELETE using slow Hash Join while equivalent SELECT uses Merge Join

Tags: amazon-redshift

We are using the recommended method defined here for performing "upserts":
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/merge-replacing-existing-rows.html

It is taking almost two minutes to load a file of just 150 rows. Almost all of this time is spent on this delete operation:

`delete
from
    measurement using measurement_temp
where
    measurement.measurement_tag_id = measurement_temp.measurement_tag_id 
    and measurement.date_time = measurement_temp.date_time`

**Even if the temp table is empty, it still takes the nearly two minutes for this operation to complete.**

It is still this slow after running a full vacuum on all tables.

Both of the columns in the predicate are part of the compound sort key, and the measurement_tag_id is the distribution key, so it's not clear to me why Redshift is taking so long.

The schema for this table looks like this:

`create table measurement(
  measurement_tag_id integer not null distkey,
  date_time timestamp not null,
  value_avg decimal(8,3),
  value_min decimal(8,3),
  value_max decimal(8,3),
  value_std_dev decimal(8,3),
  failed_qa_rule_id integer,
  primary key(measurement_tag_id, date_time),
  foreign key (measurement_tag_id) references measurement_tag(measurement_tag_id),
  foreign key (failed_qa_rule_id) references qa_rule(qa_rule_id)
)
  compound sortkey(measurement_tag_id, date_time);`

Here is the query plan for the DELETE:

`XN Hash Join DS_DIST_NONE  (cost=9.30..3368957513.17 rows=451945 width=6)
  Hash Cond: (("outer".date_time = "inner".date_time) AND ("outer".measurement_tag_id = "inner".measurement_tag_id))
  ->  XN Seq Scan on measurement  (cost=0.00..26844282.88 rows=2684428288 width=18)
  ->  XN Hash  (cost=6.20..6.20 rows=620 width=12)
        ->  XN Seq Scan on measurement_temp  (cost=0.00..6.20 rows=620 width=12)`

The equivalent SELECT returns almost instantly. Here's its query plan:

`explain
select * from measurement as m
  join measurement_temp as mt on m.measurement_tag_id = mt.measurement_tag_id and m.date_time = mt.date_time`

`XN Merge Join DS_DIST_NONE  (cost=0.00..40266436.05 rows=451945 width=144)
  Merge Cond: (("outer".measurement_tag_id = "inner".measurement_tag_id) AND ("outer".date_time = "inner".date_time))
  ->  XN Seq Scan on measurement m  (cost=0.00..26844282.88 rows=2684428288 width=68)
  ->  XN Seq Scan on measurement_temp mt  (cost=0.00..6.20 rows=620 width=76)`

So the DELETE is performing a Hash Join, while the SELECT is using a Merge Join which is much faster.

Any ideas how to speed this up? Most of the time, there isn't anything to delete (and it's still this slow), so I could add a SELECT query first to check whether it's necessary to delete anything, but it is still going to be slow for re-loading over existing data.

Comment: how big is measurement table? does vacuum first on that table make a difference

Comment: It is 2.7 billion rows, 100 GB. It is still this slow even after vacuum.

Comment: how long does that delete take? and then how long does a similar select take, using the same data? and what does the explain say about the select? select * from measurement as m join measurement_temp as mt on  m.measurement_tag_id = mt.measurement_tag_id 
    and m.date_time = mt.date_time

Comment: In the explain plan, is Redshift doing a merge join or a hash join between these two tables?

Comment: I added the query plan info.

Comment: I have the same problem and I have both `distkey` and `sortkey` set the same. Both vacuumed and analyzed. The `INNER JOIN` uses `Merge Join` in the query plan, and the `DELETE` uses a `Hash Join`.